# Press esc to stop and any other key to continue in Python

Tags: python, keyboard

Now with help of `raw_input`, I can call a method every time user presses `Enter`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
        _start()
def _start():
     print("HelloWorld")
```

There is a problem because only `Ctrl + C`, the program can be stopped. As you see, I make my program to wait user to press key.

From `opencv`, I find there is a similar need.

```
# Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

Simply I want to press esc key to exit program and press any other key to continue. So there is any way to do like this?

## In Addition

My os is OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use pynput,it's easier to use.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def _start():
     print("HelloWorld")
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
    else:
        _start()

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: From doc https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#mac-osx, I find we must run program as root.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably go the `curses` way.

```
import curses

def main():
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    while True:
        key = stdscr.getch()
        if key == 27: # This is the escape key code
             curses.endwin()
             break

main()
```

Comment: The output is very strange.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? There should be no output except for the keys that you press

Comment: Yes after I press `ESC`, the output disappear. But when the program is running, I press any other key, the format of output is very strange.

Comment: I tried this on OS X and iTerm2, are you using a different terminal?

Comment: Have you added `_start()` method?

Comment: If you are in a `curses` screen, `print` might work slightly differently. If you're talking about the fact that it doesn't go back to the start of the line, try adding a `\r` to the end of the string, like `print('HelloWorld\r')` and see if that works.