# Is there a way to getkey()/ getchar() asynchronously in python?

Tags: python, async-await

I really need an `asyncio` compatible `getkey()` so I can

```
async def stuff():
    await getkey()
```

So when the coroutine `stuff` hits the `await` our loop stops the task, and continues on another one.

I am new to coding but there sure is such a thing somewhere?

If not, it is possible to build such a coroutine or not?
The `getkey()` could return the pressed key value in any form.
But it should have `cbreak` and `noecho` on (Don't wait for enter and Don't print the pressed key).

(clarification, no real need to continue read.)

please help me^^ I know, that this way of doing it seems unusual. Curses running in it's own thread would be the right way to go. But I can use curses only for displaying.. also I am really new to coding.. and I have no time to look into this threading thing:/ I just need my 100 lines to work fluently really fast and also only once :!

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787563/press-esc-to-stop-and-any-other-key-to-continue-in-python/48788260

Comment: @acruma that's not what the question asks. The question is how to await for a keypress *asynchronously*

Comment: @acruma I uhm.. don't think this works asynchronously.

Comment: @ChatterOne thanks! I am already using curses but again if I try to screen.getkey() the code is stuck :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to actually wait for the keypress, one way is to use a thread to detect the keypress:

```
from threading import Thread
import curses

key_pressed = False

def detect_key_press():
    global key_pressed
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    key = stdscr.getch()
    key_pressed = True

def main():
    thread = Thread(target = detect_key_press)
    thread.start()
    while not key_pressed:
        print('Hello world\r')
    curses.endwin()

main()
```

It's not exactly nice to use global variables, but it's a quick way to do it.

Comment: wow threading looks actually quite easy... I love python I'll check that out now, just give me please half an hour to check it outxd but have my upvote for now!

Comment: You're doing `initscr` inside one thread and `endwin` inside another. That doesn't feel well.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a solution using `keyboard` instead of `curses`:

```
import keyboard
import time
from threading import Thread

key_pressed = False

def detect_key_press():
    global key_pressed
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
        pass
    key_pressed = True

def main():
    thread = Thread(target = detect_key_press)
    thread.start()
    while not key_pressed:
        print("Waiting for keypress...")
        time.sleep(1)
    
main()
```

Starts a `thread` inside `main` that waits for keypress